# Java swing mousemove firing only once

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

essentially I want to run a method whenever the user goes from not moving their mouse at all, to moving it. I have no clue how to go about this.

## custom listener:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class CustomMouseListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{

    //whatever other methods I have (irrelevant for the question)

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        //code goes here
        //but right now it fires every time the mouse is moved, which
        //is way too much, I only need one per move
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to implement logic for what a move is, how long must the mouse be still for it to have finished a move, etc

Comment: what is the component?

Comment: 1- You need to attach the listener to something... 2- The listener will only respond to mouse events that occur within the context of the component it is registered to... 3- If any other components within the registered component contains a mouse listener it will block events coming to this component...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know all of that and it is irrelevant. I simply want to know how I would add what I asked to a custom listener so that I can implement it, implementing it is relevant to the 3 things you have stated and I have already taken that into account in my implementation

Comment: @subash it is a JPanel that covers the entire screen

Comment: @arynaq okay, I will include that, but I still need to be able to figure out how to get it to only fire once on movement, which is the point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in knowing two things, when the mouse started to move and when the mouse stopped moving, you could use a `javax.swing.Timer` to insert a delay between events, so that it will only be tiggered when the delay is reached...

```
public class CustomMouseListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{

    private javax.swing.Timer moveTimer;
    private boolean moving = false;

    public CustomMouseListener() {
         moveTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
                         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                             moving = false;
                             // Method to be called when you want to
                             // to know when the mouse has stopped moving...
                         }
                     });
        moveTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    //whatever other methods I have (irrelevant for the question)

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        if (moving || moveTimer.isRunning()) {
            moveTimer.restart();
        } else {
            moving = true;
            moveTimer.start();
            // Method to call when you want to know when the mouse
            // has started moving...
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, when 25 milliseconds pass without `mouseMoved` being called, the `javax.swing.Timer` will be triggered....You may want to play with the threshold a little...

Comment: wont that still be called after 25 milliseconds even if it's not stopped?

Comment: but yes, this is exactly what I want if that will not let mousevents be triggered in a row

Comment: @RyanSaxe Also, when you create the timer, you need to stop it from repeating, see update...

Comment: why did you add moving?

Answer (score 3):

Plain algorithm

```
0. Fire mouse listener for every second with (x=x1, y=y1)

1. Store (x,y) of mouse pointer;
2. If (x,y) == (x1,y1) for another 15(or whatever you consider as time interval) sec
3.     make account of (x1,y1);
4. Else do nothing;
5. If(x1,y1) changed after 15 sec
6.     call mouseMove();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be save the last time it moved. If current time - lastMovedTime > x then call your listeners or mouseStartedMoving() method

public class CustomMouseListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{
public final static long TIME_DIFFERNCE_FOR_IDLE = 800;//milliseconds
    long lastMoveTime = -1;

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff =   lastMoveTime  - currentTime ;
    if(lastMoveTime == -1 || diff > TIME_DIFFERNCE_FOR_IDLE ){
        lastMoveTime();

    }

   lastMoveTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
 }

}

void  lastMoveTime(){
     //do what u need to when mouse starts mooving
 }
```

Another Need to adda polling thread. Can make a default thread pool of size 1. ADd one task (Runnable) in the run method sleep for 1 second (or 2 or 800 milliseconds - depends what you define as pause between moves)

Anyway in your original code keep track of the current mouse position x,y and expose to the runnable.

The runnable keeps track of previous mouse position. Also have a state variable in Runnable that is an enum - {INITIAL, STATIONARY, MOVING}.

Initially its INITIAL, if you get mouse move position and its INITIAL it goes to MOVING

IF MOVING and for X ticks in the Runnable it does not move goes to STATIONARY. Again on Mouse move it goes to MOVING.

When it goes from INITIAL to MOVING OR STATIONARY to MOVING, can have listeners who are called or just a special method - mouseStartedMoving()

And do whatever there.